# IntelliJ - Replace dependency to a module with dependency to the Maven artefact

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

When you delete a module from a Maven project in IntelliJ, all references to that module turn into compilation errors. Is there a way to exchange references to the module with references to the artefact in the Maven repo, so that everything still compiles?

Comment: works fine for me, I am using IntelliJ 15

Comment: Do you add your dependency to your `pom.xml` or are you expecting IntelliJ to auto-find the artifact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can get it to work after a restart of IDEA. Don't know why it didn't work at first. I delete a module, and "make project" gives me compile errors, but Maven > Reimport adds dependencies to Maven repo to replace dependencies to the deleted module. Works fine, and I can live with it being a two-step procedure :)

(My dependencies are already in pom.xml, Harmelodic. Modules are created from Maven pom.xml files.)